# Linqify this: Aggregate a subset of a list

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a list or array of items, and I want to sum a subset of the items in the list.  (in my case, it happens to always be a sequential subset).

Here's the old-fashioned way:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = startIndex; i <= stopIndex; i++)
  sum += myList[i].TheValue;
return sum;
```

What's the best way to linqify that code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myList.Skip(startIndex).Take(stopIndex - startIndex + 1).Sum(x => x.TheValue);
```

If I were doing this sort of thing a lot, I'd define a helper `TakeRange` that covered the `Skip` and `Take` so that I didn't off-by-one it.

Comment: You missed a .Select(x=>x.TheValue) before the summing.